# how to make bootstrap table including Vue Bindings?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

i am working on a vue project and i am using bootstrap for styling.
the table appear weird as you see on the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRifL.png

my code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">variant</th>
                            <th scope="col">price</th>
                            <th scope="col">quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <div v-if="!is2">
                            <div v-for="(variant, index) in options[0].variants" :key="index">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><input type="text" class="form-control" :value="variant.name" disabled> </th>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div v-if="is2">
                            <div v-for="(variant1, index) in options[0].variants" :key="index">
                                <div v-for="(variant2, vIndex) in options[1].variants" :key="vIndex">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row"><input type="text" class="form-control" :value="variant1.name +' / '+ variant2.name" disabled> </th>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're adding `div`s as  direct children of the `tbody` element which breaks the style, you could use virtual element `template` to do the conditional rendering and the loop instead of `div` like :

```
 <template v-if="!is2">
  <template v-for="(variant, index) in options[0].variants" :key="index">
   <tr>
    <th scope="row"><input type="text" class="form-control" :value="variant.name" disabled> </th>
     <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
  </tr>
 </template>
</template>
```